# Как я могу проверить инпуты на то что их заполнили?

Tags: javascript

Как я могу проверить инпуты на то что их заполнили? Хочу проверить что пользователь заполнил инпуты которые в div1 и если они не заполнены добавить к ним класс напримиер "erorr" средствами js.

```
<div class="div1">
  <input name="shirina" type="number" id="shirina" class="test" value>
  <input name="dlina" type="number" id="dlina" class="test" value>
</div>
<div class="div2">
  <input name="shirina-2" type="number" id="shirina-2" class="test" value>
  <input name="dlina-2" type="number" id="dlina-2" class="test" value>
</div>
  <button id="btn">Go</button>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Переведите ваш вопрос на Русский язык. Это SO на Русском!

Comment: Сделал на Русском языке )

Comment: [дубликаты найдутся](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На примере одного **input**

Получаете желаемый элемент из DOM дерева.
Устанавливаете событие (**addEventListener**) изменения данных в вашем **input**. 
По условию(в `input` ничего не введено) добавляется класс `error`, если поле заполнено, класс удаляется.

```js
const input = document.getElementById('shirina');
input.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  if (!e.target.value) {
    e.target.classList.add('error')
  } else {
    e.target.classList.remove('error')
  }
});
```

```css
.error {
  border: 1px solid red !important;
}

.test {
  border: 1px solid grey 
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <input name="shirina" type="number" id="shirina" class="test error" value>
</div>
```

Если хотите проверять значение не по событию изменения значения в **input**, то в нужном вам месте делаете:

```
const input = document.getElementById('shirina');
if (input.value) {
  // В поле что то введено
} else {
  // В поле ничего не введено
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!

Answer (score 1):

> и если они не заполнены добавить к ним класс напримиер "erorr" средствами js

для этих и подобных целей давным давно, в далеком далеком консорциуме придумали css псевдоклассы. использовать тут js, всё равно что с пушки по воробьям.

```css
form{display: grid}
input{background: lightblue} /* обычный */
input:valid{background: lightgreen} /* корректный */
input:invalid{background: pink} /* ошибочный */
input:required{border-left: 15px solid red} /* обязательный */
```

```html
<form>
  <input type='text' required>
  <input type='text' placeholder='text'>
  <input type='number' placeholder='number'>
  <input type='date'>
  <input type='time'>
</form>
```

p.s. вроде есть и другие, непомню, погуглите если интересно.

впрочем, они раскрашиваются заранее, еще до попыток заполнения... дабы это исправить, псевдоклассы применяйте к классу(пусть будет `.checker`), а его уже добавляйте к инпутам после ивента `onchange`.

```css
form{display: grid}
input{background: lightblue} /* обычный */
.checker:valid{background: lightgreen} /* корректный */
.checker:invalid{background: pink} /* ошибочный */
.checker:required{border-left: 15px solid red} /* обязательный */
```

```html
<form>
  <input onchange='this.classList.add("checker");' type='text' required>
  <input onchange='this.classList.add("checker");' type='text' placeholder='text'>
  <input onchange='this.classList.add("checker");' type='number' placeholder='number'>
  <input onchange='this.classList.add("checker");' type='date'>
  <input onchange='this.classList.add("checker");' type='time'>
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!