# Как вывести текст под инпутом, если он пустой?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть два инпута, мне нужно сделать так, чтобы если они были пустые, то на кнопку нельзя было нажать и под инпутами выводилось "Это поле должно быть заполнено"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот как примерно это должно выглядеть

Comment: Какие ваши попытки сделать это?

Comment: Подсмотрите [про проверку значений в input](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1473115/1473167#1473167) в самом низу ответа. Кнопке присваиваете **disabled**, в какой нибудь `div` или `span` добавляете текст с помощью `innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

параметр required для элементов html. Для его стилизации можно использовать компоненты bootstrap

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<label for="validationCustom03" class="form-label">Город</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom03" required>
<div class="invalid-feedback">
  Укажите действующий город.
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Внимательнее: "текст под инпутом"!

Comment: Подправил свой ответ для наглядности.