# Не могу сделать так чтобы при заполненных двух input можно было только нажать sabmit

Tags: javascript

```
import { throttle } from "lodash";

const form = document.querySelector(".feedback-form");
const feedbackInput = document.querySelector(".feedback-form input");
const feedbackMessage = document.querySelector(".feedback-form textarea");

const formEl = function () {
  localStorage.setItem(
    "feedback-form-state",
    JSON.stringify({
      email: feedbackInput.value,
      message: feedbackMessage.value,
    })
  );
};

const getFeedBack = function () {
  const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("feedback-form-state"));
  if (!data) return;
  feedbackInput.value = data.email;
  feedbackMessage.value = data.message;
};

const submit = function (evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  console.log({
    email: feedbackInput.value,
    message: feedbackMessage.value,
  });
  form.reset();
  localStorage.clear();
};

feedbackInput.addEventListener("input", throttle(formEl, 500));
feedbackMessage.addEventListener("input", throttle(formEl), 500);
form.addEventListener("submit", submit);

getFeedBack();
```

Comment: Посмотрите [вот этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1473115/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8/1473167#1473167) Вам надо только кнопе добавить атрибут disabled и его менять на false, когда 2 инпута заполнены

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно при submit делать проверку типа

```
feedbackInput.value.trim() != "" && feedbackMessage.value.trim() != ""
```

и если проверка не проходит не делать submit а что-нибудь другое (ну или вообще ничего)